# How prevent console window from extending beyond screen?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

If console aplication starts and system creates console window for it, but sometimes this window is created in such coordinates that some of it's contents slide out of right screen edge. Then the user must use mouse to show everything.

How to cope with that ?
What functions use to detect upper right corner coordinates of console window ?
Then I will be able to check if it is outside the screen and move the window just the distance that is needed.

What function use to move window ?
Or maybe there is all in one solution to prevent window from moving outside the screen ?

Comment: Can't you just use GetConsoleWindow()?

Comment: How you application is started? Shortcut/api?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully multi-monitor aware and taskbar aware implementation that does what you describe.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  ClampConsoleToScreen();
  return 0;
}

void ClampConsoleToScreen()
{
  HWND window = GetConsoleWindow();
  RECT windowRect;
  GetWindowRect(window, &windowRect);
  HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(window, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
  MONITORINFO mi;
  memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(mi));
  mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
  GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &mi);

  int adj, any;

  adj = 0;
  any = 0;
  if (windowRect.right > mi.rcWork.right)
  {
    // Get negative adjustment value to move it left onto screen
    adj = mi.rcWork.right - windowRect.right;
  }
  if (windowRect.left < mi.rcWork.left)
  {
    // Get positive adjustment value to move it right onto screen
    adj = mi.rcWork.left - windowRect.left;
  }
  windowRect.left += adj;
  windowRect.right += adj;
  any |= adj;

  adj = 0;
  if (windowRect.bottom > mi.rcWork.bottom)
  {
    // Get negative adjustment value to move it up onto screen
    adj = mi.rcWork.bottom - windowRect.bottom;
  }
  if (windowRect.top < mi.rcWork.top)
  {
    // Get positive adjustment value to move it down onto screen
    adj = mi.rcWork.top - windowRect.top;
  }
  windowRect.top += adj;
  windowRect.bottom += adj;
  any |= adj;

  if (any)
  {
    MoveWindow(window,
      windowRect.left,
      windowRect.top,
      windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
      windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, TRUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: As-implememented, it won't attempt to resize to maintain the "within a monitor" constraint, the top left corner will win if the width or height are excessive. It's pretty trivial to add width/height adjustment if needed.

Comment: It finds the monitor nearest to the current console window position, and if the window is entirely off all screens, chooses the primary monitor. Gets the work area for that monitor (work area excludes the taskbar, even if it is on top, etc) and adjust the window position for each edge of the workarea, pushing the monitor fully into the workarea, where the top and left edge win in conflict.